# Eset Security Suite Firewall problem

Tags: windows-7, windows, firewall, nod32

I recently upgraded from Eset NOD32 antivirus 4 to Eset Smart Security RC 5 .However i further upgraded to the latest version that is 5.0.93.0 I am using Vypress Chat and similar applications for sharing files and communicating over LAN network of my university, but I noticed I can only use these softwares once the firewall is disabled. Kindly guide me how can I add an exception for these applications. There is also interface change in Eset version 5, before that in Eset Smart Security 4 i was easily able to solve such problems.

Help me out!

Comment: Why are you using RC version of a product that went final nearly a month ago?  Use the current version of Eset Smart Security 5, if it still doesn't work, post on Eset's support forum.

Comment: Well the RC was the actual one it updated automatically and now it has updated to 5.0.93.0 version. What I meant was that there was an Interface change and more  options were added, and it is really absurd of you to ask if some person X is using some Beta product. It is usually to test it out. Does not answer my concern any way.

Comment: And actually it is actually the most current version!

Comment: RCs and Betas are RC and Beta because they may not be ready for general use. They may have problems and errors. Labeling them RC and Beta and allows regular people to download and run them allows the software developer to gain a lot of information about problems they may not have been aware of. Because of this, the question of why you installed an RC or Beta version is very valid. Does installing the release version have the same problems?

Comment: Well I am unable to add the exception for applications may be I am unable to find the option after exploring. However when I disable the firewall I can allow sharing etc be enabled.

Comment: As a self-proclaimed "software engineer" one may think you'd consider reading the documentation, KB's and perhaps contact the company that provided you the software for some assistance on how to use it's features that you can't find/grasp just by 'exploring'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the KB article for [configuring the Smart Security 5.x firewall](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2843&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1317145651784) to allow or disallow specific application exceptions. It appears to be quite the involved process, too involved to easily copy over here.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is here:
[Eset - Firewall - Windows Sharing problem](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2352&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1380128416572)
You must set firewall settings into `Interactive mode with exception`.